# Dropdown text didnt show up after get the value

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to get the value of option dropdown when the page is started without selecting it. I already successfully get the value but the text didn't show up on the dropdown interface.

Here is what I do to get the value,

```
   $("#firstDropdown").val(function () {
            getCode($(this).val());
        });
```

Comment: What `text` is bind to the selected value of dropdwon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i know so far is drop-down doesn't have `val` event, it has `.change` event.

So Change code like below:

```
$("#firstDropdown").change(function () { //.change() event
   //Use $("#firstDropdown option:selected").text() to get selected value text
    getCode($("#firstDropdown option:selected").text());
});
```

Working sample:

```js
$("#firstDropdown").change(function () {
  getCode($("#firstDropdown option:selected").text());
});

function getCode(selectedText){
  console.log(selectedText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="firstDropdown">
  <option value = "1">One</option>
  <option value = "2">Two</option>
  <option value = "3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, "the text didn't show up on the dropdown interface." Use selected on the option to show default dropdown option.

```
<select name = "dropdown">
        <option value = "1">1</option>
        <option value = "2" selected >2</option>
        <option value = "3">3</option>
     </select>
```

And to get in JS,

```
getCode($("#firstDropdown option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will do the work

```js
getSelectText('cboSelector');

$('#cboSelector').change(function(){
  getSelectText('cboSelector');
});

function getSelectText(cbo) {
  var val = $('#'+cbo).val();
  console.log($('#'+cbo+' option[value="'+val+'"]').html());
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="cboSelector">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
      </select>
```